# Does JDBCTemplate use Connections Pool by default?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a Spring Boot micro service that connects to several databases through a JDBC connection using JDBCTemplate:

```
@Bean(name = "mysqlJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("mysqlDb") DataSource dsMySQL) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsMySQL);
    }
```

I have different template for each database and then rest template controller that chooses the right template to use depending on the parameters passed in the request. 
I read the documentation, however it's not clear:

- Is a connection pool used out of the box or I need to specify it through configuration?
- In this case is a connection pool used for each JDBCTemplate?

Comment: You need to configure your pool.  Multiple templates use the same pool; not one to a customer unless you explicitly configure it to be so.

Comment: See [Connection to a Production Database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot will try to load available [connection pool](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) for your DataSource:

> Spring Boot uses the following algorithm for choosing a specific implementation:
>
> We prefer HikariCP for its performance and concurrency. If HikariCP is available, we always choose it.
>
> Otherwise, if the Tomcat pooling DataSource is available, we use it.
>
> If neither HikariCP nor the Tomcat pooling datasource are available and if Commons DBCP2 is available, we use it.
>   If you use the spring-boot-starter-jdbc or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa “starters”, you automatically get a dependency to HikariCP.
>
> You can bypass that algorithm completely and specify the connection pool to use by setting the spring.datasource.type property. This is especially important if you run your application in a Tomcat container, as tomcat-jdbc is provided by default.
>
> Additional connection pools can always be configured manually. If you define your own DataSource bean, auto-configuration does not occur.

Example of defining your own bean:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
    return MyDataSourceHolder.getDataSource();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what this ' If you define your own DataSource bean, auto-configuration does not occur.' means

Comment: @AR1 add example of defining your own bean