# Does the spring boot jdbctemplate create a new DB connection every time?

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate, spring-boot-actuator

We use spring boot actuator API for health check.

After implementing the health check (Data source), The number auth request against DB is drastically increased in LDAP. (The database user id we are using to authenticate the DB is authenticating against LDAP server)

I just checked the [DataSourceHealthIndicator code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.7.18/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/jdbc/DataSourceHealthIndicator.java#L110), they use **JDBCtemplate** for executing the query to check the DataSource health check.

Now the question is,

Does the JDBCTemplate creates a new connection every time? Will it use the connection pooling by default? Can someone explain the behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720820/does-jdbctemplate-use-connections-pool-by-default